# Как вычислить номер десятка в тысяче по заданному числу?

Tags: java, математика

Есть числа в диапазоне от 1 до 100 000.
Весь диапазон разбит на сто по тысяче. Каждая тысяча из этой сотни разбита на сто десятков.

Вопрос.

Как по рандомному числу из диапазона (1..100 000) выделить номер тысячи в первой сотне. Затем вычислить номер десятка в тысяче по номеру из первой сотни.

Пример.

1 = 1 тысяча, 1 десятка в первой тысяче
56 897 = 57 тысяча, 90 десяток в 57 тысяче

Comment: дели на соответствующее число (1000, 10 и т.д.) и округляй в большую сторону

Comment: вопрос только: 56000 - это 56 тысяча или уже 57?

Comment: @Grundy, по идее, это ещё 56 тысяча. Счёт ведь с единицы начинается

Comment: но почему во втором примере 56 тысяча упомянута, понять не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решим задачу для общего случая.

Условие:

> Натуральные числа разбиты на группы по `K` чисел. Для числа `X` определить номер группы и порядковый номер числа в группе.

Решение:

```
Номер группы: (X-1)/K + 1
Порядковый номер: (X-1)%K + 1
```

Сдвиг на единицу и обратно вызван тем, что остатки от деления на K находятся в диапазоне [0, K-1], а порядковые номера в [1, K]. Поэтому для рассчета остатков номера нужно уменьшить на один, а для рассчета номеров остатки увеличить на один.

Проверяем:

```
X = 1
K = 1000 (тысяча)
Номер тысячи: (X-1)/K + 1 = 1
Порядковый номер в тысяче: (X-1)%K + 1 = 1

X = 56897
K = 1000 (тысяча)
Номер тысячи: (X-1)/K + 1 = 57
Порядковый номер в тысяче: (X-1)%K + 1 = 897

X = 897
K = 10 (десяток)
Номер десятка: (X-1)/K + 1 = 90
```

На Java это будет два метода вроде `calcGroupNumber(int x, int k)` и `calcPosition(int x, int k)`. Для десятка в тысяче сначала находим порядковый номер в тысяче, задем номер десятка по порядковому номеру.

Comment: почему `X-1` берется?

Comment: @Grundy Именно потому, что и 999, и 1000 принадлежат одной и той же первой (или нулевой - откуда считать) тысяче...

Comment: @Akina, было бы здорово какое-нибудь обоснование добавить :)

Comment: @Grundy добавил в ответ описание в меру своих способностей :)

Comment: @defaultlocale, отлично, не заметил изменения

Comment: @defaultlocale: спасибо, помогли